# How can i make a text input on a url when using windows.open?

Tags: javascript

Would it be possible to create a site with a text input that would change a specific URL. I would essentially like a website that a viewer would be able to enter a specific id given to them in a Textbox. Whatever is in the textbox at that point will be changed in the REDIRECT URL. As you can see in the code snippet where it says "TEXTBOX TEXT WOULD GO HERE" The user would then be redirected according to whatever he/she wrote in the textbox.

Im sorry if this didn't make any sense. couldn't really explain it :)

I also added some other code if that might help.

```js
<input type="text" onKeyup="trackChange(this.value)" id="myInput">
<script>
function trackChange(value)
{

window.open("http://test.test/hello/hello?id=[TEXTBOX TEXT WOULD GO HERE]&e=[TEXTBOX TEXT WOULD GO HERE]&_=?" +value)

}
</script>

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


<script>
    var url = window.location.search;
    url = url.replace("?", '');
    location.href='http://test.test/hello/hello?id=[TEXTBOX TEXT WOULD GO HERE]&e=[TEXTBOX TEXT WOULD GO HERE]&_=?'+url;
</script>
```

Comment: You're going to open a new window after every keystroke?

Comment: You already have `"&_=" + value` at the end of the URL. What is the textbox text if it's not the same as `value`?

Comment: The +value was there to test if the input would work. Instead of whatever is inside the Textbox on the end of the url i need it within the URL itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate the value into the URL. Also use `encodeURIComponent()` to ensure that it's properly encoded.

```
function trackChange(value)
{
    value = encodeURIComponent(value);
    window.open("http://test.test/hello/hello?id=" + value + "&e=" + value + "&_=?");
}
```